# python distutils / setuptools: how to exclude a module, or honor svn:ignore flag

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I have a python project, 'myproject', that contains several packages. one of those packages, 'myproject.settings', contains a module 'myproject.settings.local' that is excluded from version control via 'svn:ignore' property.

I would like setuptools to ignore this file when making a bdist or bdist_egg target.

I have experimented with find_packages(exclude..) to no avail. Ideally I was hoping that only files that are not ignored by svn would be included.

Is there a way to achieve the exclusion of my module? 
(I am on a patched (http://bugs.python.org/setuptools/issue64) version of setuptools trunk, with subversion 1.6.)

thanks for any insight you might have

-frank

Comment: did you have a solution ? I'm facing this issue today too when I try to exclude my local settings too from a django project.

Comment: I have posted my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50592100/2650249).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a regular way to do that but you you try a workaround like proposed in the [How can I make setuptools ignore subversion inventory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129180/how-can-i-make-setuptools-ignore-subversion-inventory)

svn export your package to a temporary directory, run the setup.py from there