# How to exclude a single file from package with setuptools and setup.py

Tags: python, package, setuptools, pypi

I am working on `blowdrycss`. The repository is [here](https://github.com/nueverest/blowdrycss).

I want the settings file for `blowdrycss_settings.py` to be excluded from the final package on pypi. The intention is to dynamically build a custom settings file that will be placed in the users virtualenv / project folder.

In `setup.py`, I have the following:

```
packages=find_packages(exclude=['blowdrycss_settings.py', ]),
```

I also tried [exclude_package_data](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files):

```
exclude_package_data={
    '': ['blowdrycss_settings.py'],
    '': ['blowdrycss/blowdrycss_settings.py'],
    'blowdrycss': ['blowdrycss_settings.py'],
},
```

I then run `python setup.py sdist bdist`.

However, when I look in the build folder I still see `blowdrycss_settings.py`:

```
- build 
    - lib
        - blowdrycss_settings.py
```

It seems like it should be simple to just exclude a file.

How do I exclude `blowdrycss_settings.py` from the distributed package?

Comment: Have you tried using [`exclude_package_data`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files)?

Comment: I have not. I was not aware it existed.

Comment: I am using the following `exclude_package_data={'': ['blowdrycss_settings.py'], },` and it is still not excluding the file as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

Underneath of `blowdrycss`, I created a new module called `settings` so the directory structure now looks like this:

```
blowdrycss
    blowdrycss
        settings
            blowdrycss_settings.py
```

Based on this [reference](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages), inside of `setup.py` I have the following:

```
packages=find_packages(exclude=['*.settings', ]),
```

To build the distribution:

1. Delete the `build`, `dist`, and `.egg-info` folders.
2. Run `python setup.py sdist bdist`

In retrospect, it is good that I was unable to do what I was originally attempting. The new structure feels cleaner and is more modular.

Comment: Step one shoul'nt be mentioned in a subclause. It's a very important step and a very annoying circumstance about setuptools or distutils respectively which introduces history artefacts.

Comment: @nu everest, can we exclude some files/packages at root level dynamically by passing some arguments to setup.py file while running pip?

Answer (score 5):

Imagine you have a project

```
root
├── setup.py
└── spam
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── bacon.py
    └── eggs.py
```

and you want to exclude `spam/eggs.py` from packaging:

```
import fnmatch
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py as build_py_orig


excluded = ['spam/eggs.py']


class build_py(build_py_orig):
    def find_package_modules(self, package, package_dir):
        modules = super().find_package_modules(package, package_dir)
        return [
            (pkg, mod, file)
            for (pkg, mod, file) in modules
            if not any(fnmatch.fnmatchcase(file, pat=pattern) for pattern in excluded)
        ]


setup(
    packages=find_packages(),
    cmdclass={'build_py': build_py}
)
```

Globs and multiple entries in `excluded` list will work too because it is consumed by `fnmatch`, so you can e.g. declare

```
excluded = [
    'modules_in_directory/*.py',
    'modules_in_subtree/**/*.py',
    'path/to/other/module.py'
]
```

etc.

This recipe is based on [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50592100/2650249) to the question [setup.py exclude some python files from bdist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5974982/2650249)
. The difference is that this recipe excludes modules based on file globs, while the other one excludes modules based on qualnames, for example

```
excluded = ['spam.*', '*.settings']
```

will exclude all submodules of `spam` package and all modules named `settings` in every package and subpackage etc.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to remove a *single*, or at least a few specific files, from a package with `setuptools` is just to use the `MANIFEST.in`. For example, in a package you can exclude all files name `foo.py` by simply specifying `global-exclude foo.py`. There's no need for `setuptools` hacking or changing the structure of your package if you just use the `MANIFEST.in` method.

See the dedicated [PyPA article on using `MANIFEST.in`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/) for more commands you can use.

Comment: This should be the canonical answer

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the [manifest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68043232), this is what our manifest file looks like:

```
recursive-include src/MyPackage *
recursive-exclude src/MyPackage *.pyc
recursive-exclude src/MyPackage/excluded-directory *.py
```