# Exclude a folder from a python package for uploading a package to PyPI

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, pypi, python-packaging

Right now a have my `packages` variable in `setup.py` defined like this:

```
packages=find_packages(include=['zeption'])
```

But `zeption` has a folder `examples` I want to exclude:

```
zeption/
├── ...
├── setup.py
├── ...
└── zeption
    ├── ...
    ├── examples <----- want to exclude
    ├── ...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: 'Private' module in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602110/python-private-module-in-a-package)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The question is not about private submodules but rather on how to excule a folder when uploading a package to PyPI

Comment: @pythad: Does `examples` contain an `__init__.py` file?  I don't think the directory will be included without one.  (Though it could be included due to being treated as package data instead of code.)

Comment: @pythad My mistake. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115892/how-to-exclude-a-single-file-from-package-with-setuptools-and-setup-py) may help then.

Comment: `find_packages` also takes an `exclude` kwarg

Answer (score 2):

Just specify the `exclude` kwarg:

```
packages=find_packages(include=['zeption'], exclude=['zeption.examples', ])
```