# Exclude single source file from python bdist_egg or bdist_wheel

Tags: setuptools, python-wheel, egg

Background: I have one source file which is responsible for security. In there are magic keys and specific algorithms.

Is it possible to remove a this single source file from a python egg or wheel package?

I already accomplished to ship only binarys with the the egg command.

```
python setup.py bdist_egg --exclude-source-files
```

Edit Project structure:

```
├── setup.py
├── src
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── file1.py
|   ├── file2.py
|   ├── file_to_exclude.py
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Excluding single modules is tricky. Can you provide your project structure?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your help. I updated the post above.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a better solution than what I've suggested earlier; if you're still interested, check it out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither `distutils` nor `setuptools` provide a possibility to exclude single modules, so you have to work around it.

### Update:

I have described a better solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50592100/2650249) that mimics the package exclusion `setuptools` does in `find_packages()`. You will have to override the `build_py` command in the setup script that can accept a list of exclude patterns, same as `exclude` list in `find_packages`. In your case, it would be:

```
import fnmatch
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py as build_py_orig


exclude = ['src.file_to_exclude']


class build_py(build_py_orig):

    def find_package_modules(self, package, package_dir):
        modules = super().find_package_modules(package, package_dir)
        return [(pkg, mod, file, ) for (pkg, mod, file, ) in modules
                if not any(fnmatch.fnmatchcase(pkg + '.' + mod, pat=pattern)
                for pattern in exclude)]


setup(
    ...,
    packages=find_packages(),
    cmdclass={'build_py': build_py},
)
```

I find this to be a much more powerful and `distutils`-conform solution than the ones below. It also enables one to exclude multiple modules via wildcard matching, for example

```
exclude = ['src.file*']
```

will exclude all modules starting with `file` in `src` package, or

```
exclude = ['*.file1']
```

will exclude `file1.py` in all packages.

### Original answer

#### put modules to be excluded in a separate package

You can use the fact that `setuptools` can exclude packages (dirs containing the `__init__.py` files), but it will require some refactoring. Create a `package_to_exclude`, put `file_to_exclude.py` in there and fix all the eventual import errors:

```
project
├── setup.py
└── src
     ├── __init__.py
     ├── file1.py
     ├── file2.py
     └── package_to_exclude
          ├── __init__.py
          └── file_to_exclude.py
```

Now you can exclude `package_to_exclude` in the setup script:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    ...,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['src.package_to_exclude'])
)
```

#### exclude package, add modules to be included via `py_modules`

If you can't or don't want to move the module in a separate package, you can exclude the `src` package and add all the modules in `src` except `file_to_exclude` in `py_modules`. Example:

```
import os
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

excluded_files = ['file_to_exclude.py']
included_modules = ['src.' + os.path.splitext(f)[0]
                    for f in os.listdir('src')
                    if f not in excluded_files]

setup(
    ...,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['src']),
    py_modules=included_modules,
)
```